# Can AC mains induce a negative voltage in my photodetector circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, photodiode

A smart meter, such as the one in the picture below emits a red light from an LED based on the power consumption (while I was measuring it, it was around 7 sec on 7 sec off i.e. ~0.25kw).

The emitting LED is labelled 1 Wh/imp, as shown.

[image]

I constructed the circuit below on some veroboard:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0zSCFm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21810f.pdf) of the op amp I used.

[Datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83471/tefd4300.pdf) of the photodiode I used. (note that the angle of sensitivity is 20 degrees, so it's quite a weak signal, even with a 1MOhm resistor.)

- At ambient light (indoors), the circuit registers about +250mV.
- Outdoors, it climbs to about +1V max.
- If I cover the entire circuit (that is, put the whole thing in a box, seal it from all corners, put it inside a dark wardrobe, I get about +100mV at the output.

Problem:

I stuck the device onto the steel case of the switchboard, with the photodiode directly opposite the red led of the smart meter. I then completely closed the switchboard so that there is no light into the box, with only the probes to my multimeter coming out of it.

I measured approx. -35mV and -55mV. I checked the polarity of my multimeter many times, and the voltage measured is definitely negative (as soon as I open the switchboard the voltage goes back to around +250mV.

As I said earlier, the house is drawing around 250W according to the emitting LED. That's only 1A, and the wires are behind the meter.

The circuit is powered by 4x1.2V batteries, and the mains voltage is 240VAC.

So, why is the circuit reading a negative voltage?

Edit:

I just checked again, and if I set the multimeter to AC, I get 0.3V.

Answer (score 2):

You've built a little radio receiver (Diode, high gain wideband amplifier), and are probably  receiving something with it. Your multimeter can't show you the high frequency signal, but you get the detected output.

The smart-meter may have a radio transmitter. It's usually part of some sort of mesh network at around 900 or 2400 MHz. The dumb-meter definitely creates magnetic fields at 50 or 60 Hz. Either of these could be picked up by your circuit, or the multimeter itself.

Try some basic [EMC mitigation tricks](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/circuits/emc-emi/design-techniques-for-emc.php):

- Keep all leads short
- Twist wires together, particularly the ones between the photodiode and the circuit
- put small capacitors everywhere.  100 nF between the power supply rails, 100 pF from the diode to ground and op-amp output to ground, to shunt the RF to ground
- Shield the cable going to the photodiode (use a length of coax instead of twisted wire)
- Change the length of the wire between circuit and diode - it might be a good antenna at 900 MHz, and a small length change could spoil that.
- Don't earth your circuit to the box, that just makes the antenna work better.

You should also consider using a [phototransistor](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv16=2&pv16=10267&FV=fff4001e%2Cfff803c9%2Ca00021%2Ca00033%2Ca00048%2Ca0005c%2Ca0006e&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) instead of a photodiode. Choose one that's sensitive to visible light (most are for IR). They are a hundred times more sensitive. In my experience you can easily connect them straight to the ADC pin of a microcontroller with a simple pull-up resistor; light to dark could be a few volts change.

Comment: The photodiode is soldered directly onto the veroboard, and the entire circuit (it's only about 1 sq. inch) is inside the switchboard - would this be worse or better?

Comment: That's best. Still, try some capacitors. An experiment - wrap the whole circuit in black electrical tape or a dark plastic bag and wave it around the meter box. See if the negative voltage is sensitive to position. That will tell you for sure if it's interference.

Comment: I did some testing on my work bench, and I think you're correct. The AC component rises quite a bit when completely dark. I turned off my phone and router and other RF devices nearby, and the AC voltage dropped to almost zero. First time experiencing EMI first hand - very fascinating. I'll update you once I get a proper circuit with capacitors going.

Comment: Cool. I was specifically thinking of the smartmeter as a source of interference. If it has a radio, it'll be about 1 W, it transmits all the time, and it's in a closed metal box with your circuit. Try sniffing around in the box too.

Comment: You can kill the high-frequency gain of your op-amp by putting a capacitor across the 1MΩ resistor. It'll basically roll off the gain by the photodiode's impedance (at the frequency (Fc): \$F_{C}=\frac{1}{2 \pi RC}\$, where `R` is the diode impedance (probably ~1MΩ, ballpark), and `C` is your capacitor). Doing this should help a fair bit.

Comment: Connor is right.  There's a lesson about bandwidth here,  if you only need a few hertz then it's a good idea to add filtering (ie a capacitor or 2) to limit the bandwidth down to that.  Amplifying signals that you aren't looking for is a common source of problems.

Comment: @ConnorWolf By adding a capacitor parallel to R1, aren't you essentially creating an inverting active low pass filter? If so, isn't the corner frequency determined by C and R1, not the diode impedance?

Comment: @tgun926 - No, R1 is in parallel with the capacitor, not across it, so it doesn't affect the gain rolloff. All R1 does is set the maximum gain. Basically, at high frequencies, the capacitor acts like a short, so you basically have a infinite attenuator. At DC, the capacitor acts like an open circuit. In between, your gain is \$ V_{Gain} = \frac{R1||Capacitor}{R_{diode}}\$.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I have posted a [separate](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145428/calculating-capacitor-value-for-high-frequency-attenuation) question regarding this as I'm still unsure.

Comment: @tomnexus Did a bit more testing - I think it might be the multimeter (or both). I waved the leads around the switchboard and was getting quite a strong (100mV) AC reading, even with very short (5cm) leads. When I grounded one end to the switchboard metal case, the reading was even higher. Is there a chance that the circuit is correct, and the multimeter is the problem? I also added a few capacitors for HF suppression.

Comment: A multimeter not connected to anything might read some stray voltage. But the output impedance of the op amp is low. So a more fair test would be to short the multimeter probes together, and then wave that around the switchboard. If it's the 900 MHz RF energy, it'll still couple into the shorted probes, so if you see voltage then, the multimeter is the problem.